# How to Implement Flutter Functions

Tags: flutter

With reference to a Stack Ordering solution ([Flutter - changing a Stack Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308510/flutter-changing-a-stack-order))

Summary - I have a stack of widgets I want to reorder. The solution is to use functions to recreate the correct order of widgets. In the example linked to above works (great!). However, the example widgets were small - no issue to simply repeat the same code to re-order.

My real world example - the stack of widgets is reasonably complex and I have refactored into functions to reuse between the stack order functions:

Let's say the original stack has this as one of the widgets in the stack:

```
    final statusMessage = new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
    child: new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        new Text(
          statusText, 
          style: themeData.textTheme.subhead,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter);
```

I have been declaring all these widgets in the single Widget build class.

The functions to reorder the stacks are outside of this build function. An example:

```
 void swapStackChildren() {
     setState(() {
        stackChildren = [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: statusMessage,
            key: GlobalKey(),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: widget2,  // a complex widget
            key: GlobalKey(),
          ),
         etc....
        ];
   });
```

}

Ideally, I need a way to (forward) reference the widgets in swapStackChildren that are declared in the build method or a way to reference 'context' outside of the build method so I can reference themeData.

Perhaps it is my lack of understanding of the structure/layout of a page? I have only one Widget build class where I am declaring all my widgets (header, content area, buttons, etc) and these cannot be referenced by functions in the preceding code.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. Just insert the widgets in a different order to the list.

Comment: The problem is not with the original solution- it works. The problem - I need to reference the widgets in the swop function. The swop function is declared before the Widget build() class. The build class contains the widget definitions. Is the the correct pattern - define widgets in the Widget class?  I cannot forward reference functions further down the source code. If I take the widgets out of the build class, I don't know how to refence 'context'. I would like to understand best practise.

Comment: I think a proper pattern would be to update state in `setState()` and use `build()` to build the widget tree. What you are doing is building widgets in `setState()` which doesn't look good. You can still maintain a list of IDs or whatever in `setState()` that is then used in `build()` to derive the right order of widgets.

Comment: Thanks Gunter - I agree. Can you provide a example of how to maintain a list of ID's, rather then the Widgets themselves? I presume this is the Key attribute? I think this would resolve my problem.

Comment: How do you determine the original order?